# State Space model of a positional servo system. What are these parameters?

Tags: motor, control, servo

I am trying to solve a problem related to state space modelling of a positional servo system. I am stuck in the last part of the question. The full questoin is shown below:

> The following question refers to the following plant state-space model with the sampling time being 0.1s.

[image]

[image]

To my understanding:

```
% returns K matrix 
K = place(A,B, poles); 

initial_state = [0.4 0 0]';
desired_state = [1 0 0]';
```

I do not understand the meaning of \$h\$ in \$M_o(t) = 0.07h(t-3)Nm\$ and the subsequent control signal. (Thank you @Chu for pointing this out)

The control signal is given by \$u(k) = K[x_d - x(k)] = r - Kx(k)\$ but I have no mention of the value for \$x(k)\$ and \$r\$. Knowing \$x(k)\$ I would be able to get the control signal.

If these terms are not given as part of the question should they be obtained frmo knowledge of positional control servo systems? How can I proceed with the question if I do not know \$x(k)\$ which I need to get the input signal?

---

**EDIT**

I have still been unable to solve this issue.

\$x(k)\$ referes to the state vector which in a positional servo system would represent the angular velocity, displacement and current. I am thinking that this shuold be equal to the initial condition \$x_o\$

Going through Ogata Control Engineernig I come across a similar system:

[image]

Comment: \$h(t)\$ is the unit step function. \$h(t-3)\$ is the unit step function delayed by 3 time units.

Comment: "Knowing x(k) I would be able to get the control signal." express that control as a feedback law \$ u(t) = -Kx(k)\$ and use linear algebra to incorporate that into the dynamics of the system, like, add the \$ A-BK\$.